# Simply Apache virtual host configuration not working

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, localhost, virtualhost

I'm tying to configure Apache for running phpmyadmin in it's own folder, using phpmyadmin.local server name. I'm not an Apache "guru" and i can't figure out why this is not working. Any help would be much appreciated. **The error** is: it's redirecting me on my ISP search page (like DNS not working).

hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 phpmyadmin.local
```

httpd-vhosts.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/Users/Marco/Documents/www"

    <Directory "C:/Users/Marco/Documents/www">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName phpmyadmin.local
    DocumentRoot "C:/Users/Marco/Documents/www/phpMyAdmin-3.4.5-english"

    <Directory "C:/Users/Marco/Documents/www/phpMyAdmin-3.4.5-english">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: "Not working" is never a good error description. What exactly happens? What error messages do you get?

Comment: Do you have the NameVirtualHost setting in the main httpd.conf?

Comment: @davidethell no NameVirtualHost defined in httpd.conf!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the virtualhost definitions put this line:

```
NameVirtualHosts *:80
```

When trying to access the URL from the browser be sure to type http:// before the url.